# Can I add the custom fields to the product listing page in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Each product has the custom fields options.  Can I output those custom fields on each product item in the product list page?  If so, how?  I have tried adding the ProductOtherDetails and the %%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFieldItem%% in the CategoryProductsItem.html, but got no output at all of any of the items I have tried.  Any suggestions or pointers on how and if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2015, you can now access %%GLOBAL_ProductCustomFields%% on any template file that renders a particular panel's individual items. For example:

-Snippets/CategoryProductsItem.html for category list pages 
-Snippets/HomeFeaturedProductsItem.html for the featured products panel

I recommend adding the custom field name as a class to each field for easy hiding, and accessing of the value in case the custom fields ever change you won't be accessing them via :nth-child CSS which would break. You can do so by modify Snippets/ProductCustomFieldItem.html to add the custom field name to the CSS class or ID like this:

```
<div class="DetailRow %%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%">
    <div class="Label">%%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%:</div>
    <div class="Value">
        %%GLOBAL_CustomFieldValue%%
    </div>
</div>​
```

Doing so, will output like this in each item in the category list.

[image]

Above, I am using the custom fields to send through shipping time, as well as "Starting At" to prepend to the list page price if the item is a parent which has children of higher prices. In my opinion, these features greatly increase the user experience.

For **Faceted Search** (handlebars.js)

I recommend adding this to Panels/FacetedSearchProductGrid.html:

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}

    {{ id }} : {{ name }} : {{ value }}

{{/each}}
```

Comment: Wow Tim, I will be trying this out. I had no idea you could access the Global_ProductCustomFields.  Was this in a Blog post or in the Developer documentation?
I don't have an enterprise account, so I don't have access to the faceted search.  But the other code looks like a great solution. I will let you know how it comes out.

Comment: Glad I could help. Our partner rep at BC let us know about this sometime last month, although I haven't found anything about it in the documentation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Those filters will be limited to the Product pages specifically. The only way around it is to hash together a solution using jQuery to go and fetch items in question from the product page. A pain, but do-able with unnecessary effort.